# cut off about 20px on both side - mobile website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

http://juniorgoldreport.com/ is the website I'm working on. It's made in wordpress. I'm making it mobile friendly by doing all my changes with

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

I'm viewing all my changes via chromes inspect element on a desktop, and then using the mobile view.

When you take a look at the website, there's extra space on the right and left, maybe like 20/30px's. I'd want to cut that extra space out so it more zoomed in, that the articles are taking up the whole screen (maybe 2px away from both sides of the screen).

I'm not sure what I need to change to make this happen. I've been screwing around with so many elements but I can't find one that does any sort of direct change to website's sizing.

example images:

This is how it is now
[image: current mobile website]

this is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `.entry-content` element has a `max-width` set at 604px. Try removing this line :

```
    max-width: 604px;
```

From here :

```
@media (max-width: 999px){
    .sidebar .entry-header, .sidebar .entry-content, .sidebar .entry-summary, .sidebar .entry-meta, .sidebar .comment-list, .sidebar .comment-reply-title, .sidebar .comment-navigation, .sidebar .comment-respond .comment-form, .sidebar .featured-gallery, .sidebar .post-navigation .nav-links, .author.sidebar .author-info {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. That was exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Find this code in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 999px){
.sidebar .entry-header, .sidebar .entry-content, .sidebar .entry-summary, .sidebar .entry-meta, .sidebar .comment-list, .sidebar .comment-reply-title, .sidebar .comment-navigation, .sidebar .comment-respond .comment-form, .sidebar .featured-gallery, .sidebar .post-navigation .nav-links, .author.sidebar .author-info {
```

And change the max-width in it. I tested it at 100% and it seemed to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at line 2267 of your style.css.

20px of left and right padding are being applied to #content .entry-content (along with a number of other things).

```
#content .entry-header,  #content .entry-content,  #content .entry-summary,  #content footer.entry-meta,  #content .featured-gallery,  .search.sidebar .page-content,  .blog.sidebar .page-content,  .sidebar .post-navigation .nav-links,  .paging-navigation .nav-links,  #content .author-info,  .comments-area .comments-title,  .comments-area .comment-list,  .comments-area .comment-navigation,  .comment-respond,  .sidebar .site-info,  .sidebar .paging-navigation .nav-links {padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;}
```